# How to compile properly a document using "fontspec" package?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec

How to compile properly a document using `fontspec` package?

Example code (15.1. XeTeX @ LaTeX-wikibooks.pdf)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{document}
```

Result with `$latex fontspec.tex`

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.1415926-1.40.9 (Web2C 7.5.7)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./fontspec.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, german-x-2008-06-18, ngerman-x-2008-06-18, ancientgreek, ibycus, ar
abic, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutc
h, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, ngerman, mono
greek, greek, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, la
tin, mongolian, mongolian2a, bokmal, nynorsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, rus
sian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, ukenglis
h, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3names.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3intexpr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3seq.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.129 \int_new:N
               \g_seq_nesting_depth_int
?
```

Result with `$lualatex fontspec.tex`

```
This is LuaTeX, Version snapshot-0.25.4-2009102410 (Web2C 7.5.7)
(fontspec.tex>
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, german-x-2008-06-18, ngerman-x-2008-06-18, ancientgreek, ibycus, ar
abic, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutc
h, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, ngerman, mono
greek, greek, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, la
tin, mongolian, mongolian2a, bokmal, nynorsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, rus
sian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, ukenglis
h, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3names.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/luatex-loader.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.luatex.lua)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/scripts/oberdiek/oberdiek.pdftexcmds.lua)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3intexpr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3seq.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.129 \int_new:N
                 \g_seq_nesting_depth_int
?
```

Result with `$xelatex fontspec.tex`

```
This is XeTeXk, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.999.6 (Web2C 7.5.7)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./fontspec0.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, german-x-2008-06-18, ngerman-x-2008-06-18, ancientgreek, ibycus, ar
abic, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutc
h, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, ngerman, mono
greek, greek, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, la
tin, mongolian, mongolian2a, bokmal, nynorsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, rus
sian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, ukenglis
h, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/xelatex/expl3/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/xelatex/expl3/l3names.sty>

! Package l3names Error: Required primitive not found: \pdfstrcmp.>

See the l3names package documentation for explanation.>
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.>
 ...>

l.121     }>
```

Second example (#2:3 Test F-autofake @ fontspec/fontspec-testsuite.pdf)

```
\documentclass{testsuite}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\Large
\def\text{ABC \textit{ABC} \textbf{ABC}
          \textbf{\textit{ABC}}\\}
\fontspec{Inconsolata}
\fontspec[AutoFakeSlant]{Inconsolata}
\fontspec[AutoFakeBold]{Inconsolata}
\fontspec[AutoFakeSlant,AutoFakeBold]
         {Inconsolata}
\fontspec[AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Inconsolata}
\fontspec[AutoFakeBold=5]{Inconsolata}
\fontspec[AutoFakeSlant=0.4,AutoFakeBold=5]
         {Inconsolata}
\end{document}
```

Result with `$latex/lualatex/xelatex fontspec1.tex`

```
This is XeTeXk, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.999.6 (Web2C 7.5.7)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./fontspec1.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, german-x-2008-06-18, ngerman-x-2008-06-18, ancientgreek, ibycus, ar
abic, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danish, dutc
h, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, galician, german, ngerman, mono
greek, greek, hungarian, icelandic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, la
tin, mongolian, mongolian2a, bokmal, nynorsk, polish, portuguese, romanian, rus
sian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, ukenglis
h, ukrainian, uppersorbian, welsh, loaded.>

! LaTeX Error: File `testsuite.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:

(./fontspec.sty (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3names.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3intexpr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/expl3/l3seq.sty
! Undefined control sequence.
l.129 \int_new:N
                 \g_seq_nesting_depth_int
?
```

Please, may you tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Your question has severe formatting problems (code/pre mixup). Please fix them.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). This works much better than `<pre>` here :-)

Comment: Also, don't call your file 'fontspec.tex' when you are using the `fontspec` package.

Comment: @jon You should be okay here, but you are quite right that there are some packages where this could be a disaster.

Comment: @JosephWright -- Ah, I wondered (but didn't test).  I once got burned with this when trying something with a `pstricks` module, IIRC....

Comment: @jon Yes, that would be one. It happens where you have a `foo.sty` which loads 'payload' `foo.tex`. Often seen with packages that work with plain TeX as well as with LaTeX.

Answer (score 13):

Your TeX installation is too old to use `fontspec`. You need at least XeTeX 0.9994 or LuaTeX 0.40, as detailed in the [LaTeX3 README](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/l3kernel/README.markdown) and other documentation. You will need to install more up to date binaries, which realistically means an updated TeX Live (I see you are on Unix).

Comment: In particular, LuaTeX has changed a _lot_ since v0.25. Currently, we are on the v0.70 branch, and there have been a lot of changes to the Lua side.