# How to compile properly a document using “fontspec” package? Part 2

Tags: xetex, fontspec

## Update

I followed Joseph Wright's suggestion of updating MikTeX in normal and admin modes, but am still unable to successfully compile the document. Here is the current [log as a gist](https://gist.github.com/fgnu/071669d7974eb0dbc49b).

---

## Original question

This question may well be a duplicate in that I do not understand the [advice given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65959/8863) to the [question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65958/8863).

I am trying to compile a document with XeLaTeX, but run into all sorts of difficulties relating to required fonts, and from a little bit of googling, it appears that this is related to the use of the `fontspec` package.

I put together an MWE just as in the linked question, and ran that through XeLaTeX:

**TestFontspec.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{document}
```

**Output of TestFontspec.tex**

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode

(F:\programming\r\examples\example52[BuildWickhamBook]\Examples\example1\TestFo
ntspec.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, 
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3names.sty
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3bootstrap.sty))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty")
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3basics.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3expan.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3tl.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3seq.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3int.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3quark.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prg.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3clist.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3token.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3prop.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3msg.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3file.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3skip.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3keys.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3fp.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3box.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3coffins.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3color.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3luatex.sty)
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3candidates.sty)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-patches.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fixltx2e.sty")
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.
*************************************************
) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
(F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"))))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg"
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tl 
                                fontspec/Ligatures/Historical
l.8 ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}

? ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \c_keys_code_root_tl 
                                fontspec/Ligatures/Historic
l.8 ...tureoption{Ligatures}{Historic}{Historical}

? OK, entering \batchmode
```

It seems that my installation of XeLaTeX is up to date (linked question says that it should be v0.9994). How can I correctly compile this MWE?

Comment: You have mismatched versions of `fontspec` and `l3kernel`. You have the classic issue with MiKTeX: you need to run 'update' in both a 'normal' and 'admin' modes.

Comment: @JosephWright I have updated MikTeX in normal and admin modes, and here is the current log: https://gist.github.com/fgnu/071669d7974eb0dbc49b. The output is still deformed and XeLaTeX tells me there are 43 errors.

Comment: Your log shows `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty` but `F:\programming\miktex\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3names.sty`: those files are in two different roots, so you do have an updating issue. In the log you link to, it's the copy of `fontspec` that is old.

Comment: You obviously didn't update the packages in C:\program Files. Start the `update manager (admin)` and run the updates.

Comment: @JosephWright It had completely slipped my mind that I had two separate installations of MikTeX. I am in the process of updating both, cleaning up the paths, and will report back to this thread.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks so much for your timely help. I removed the older MikTeX installation, and now all works well. Points to you if you want to put it all together in an answer.

Comment: it is only one warning you get. Otherwise it works fine. You can run the code with xelatex or lualatex. In both the case you get warning only.*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to conflicting TeX distributions on the same machine.